# Open Office assembly folder

Tags: c#, openoffice-writer

I googled "Open Office C#" and found a commonly reoccurring tutorial: http://www.opendocument4all.com/download/OpenOffice.net.pdf

The trouble is this portion (snippet from pdf):

> Change from the Visual Studio window to a Explorer window. Move to the
>   CLI assemblies folder. You will find them in your OpenOffice program
>   installation path in the folder named “assembly”. In this folder you
>   should see the following .net assemblies.

I do not have this "assembly" folder. I navigated to:
C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenOffice.org 3

It simply is not there. I have to create reports using C#.

Comment: In which file format the reports need to be exactly ? ODT ? DOC ? DOCX ? RTF ? PDF ?

Comment: The file format needs to be in DOC or DOCX

Comment: please see my answer below... there is a free library from MS to create DOCX... if it needs to be DOC I included a link to a commercial library that can do that if need be...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments above from the OP the goal is to create DOC or DOCX:

For creating DOCX there is a FREE option ([OpenXML from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb448854%28office.14%29.aspx)) available...

For creating the older DOC format (among lots of other things there is for example [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx) (commercial - just a happy customer, not affilliated).

**EDIT - as per comment:**

All above options work independently of Word (i.e. don't need Office present/installed on the machine).

Comment: Will this allow me to create graphs and what-not without requiring Microsoft Word to be installed on the computer?

Comment: @StormKiernan yes - absolutely :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure Yahia understood what you were asking...

As, I had the same issue (I think), I thought I would share the solution I found:

In version(s) 3.x+ the cli_* dlls are placed in the GAC and (afak) inaccessible from a VisualStudio project.  You have to extract them from the openofficeorg1.cab file (using RAR, WinZip, 7z, whatever).

Here is a link that goes into more detail covering the topic:
http://blog.nkadesign.com/2008/net-working-with-openoffice-3/

BTW, when I did this (successfully), I found 6 such cli_* dlls.

It's worth mentioning that when I came across this tidbit, I had already deleted the initial installation folder that was created during the setup, so I had to uninstal OpenOffice and then reinstall to get that folder back.  After that it was easy.

Hope this was of some help.